# Android Studio cannot update to latest support libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to upgrade my android support libraries to the latest versions, eg.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
}
```

However, when I run the gradle sync, these libraries cannot be resolved:

```
Error:(30, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.0.0
Install Repository and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Clicking "Install Repository and sync project" does nothing.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410761/cannot-upgrade-to-latest-support-library-android-studio) suggests it might be due to not having the `google()` repository in my build.gradle. However, if I add it and try to sync, I get "Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'. It lists possible causes:

1. The project 'xyz' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
   Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project <= I am using "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'"
2. The project 'xyz' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file. <= using gradle 3.3
3. The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin. <= Again, the gradle plugin is listed in the dependencies of the build file.

How can I upgrade to the latest Android support libraries?

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you follow the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#add-library) regarding how to set up your support libraries. (Works for Android Studio 2.3.3)

> **Adding Support Libraries**
>
> In order to use a Support Library, you must modify your application's project's classpath dependencies within your development environment. You must perform this procedure for each Support Library you want to use.
>
> To add a Support Library to your application project:
>
> 1. Open the build.gradle file for your application.
> 2. Make sure that the repositories section includes a maven section with the "https://maven.google.com" endpoint. For example:
>
> ```
>     allprojects {
>         repositories {
>             jcenter()
>             maven {
>                 url "https://maven.google.com"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```
>
> 3. Add the support library to the dependencies section. For example, to add the v4 core-utils library, add the following lines:
>
> ```
>      dependencies {
>               ...
>               compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.0"
>           }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried following these instructions. The project compiles successfully with the additional repository added, so I think that issue is fixed. But when I upgrade my dependency versions I now get some random "Error:(15, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'." in xyz/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values-v26/values-v26.xml. This is Android Studio 2.3.3.

Comment: @tytk Try cleaning and rebuilding the project. That may take care of the problem. Glad the linked instructions worked for you.

Comment: Updated dependency versions, ran `./gradlew clean`, then synced the project. Got the same error unfortunately.

Comment: @tytk That one is a mystery to me. You may want to consider posting a new question.

Comment: @tytk You need compileSdkVersion 26, too